# Json query String for getting value with Condition

Tags: java, json, json-query

I want to get the value of `vehicleCode`element where `vehicleLease` is `AS PER LAW OF ENFORCMENT`.

Could someone please help me with JSON query ?

Please find JSON data below.

```
    {
    "StateOffers": [
        [{
                "vehicleCode": 242214214,
                "vehiclePart": [{
                        "@type": "vehiclePart",
                        "segments": [{
                                "@type": "Segment"
                                "segmentOfferInformation": {
                                    "vehicleMiles": 771,
                                    "awardFare": false
                                },
                                "vehicleLease": "AS PER LAW OF ENFORCMENT"
                            }
                        ],
                        "stops": 0
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "vehicleCode": 242214214,
                "vehiclePart": [{
                        "@type": "vehiclePart",
                        "segments": [{
                                "@type": "Segment"
                                "segmentOfferInformation": {
                                    "vehicleMiles": 771,
                                    "awardFare": false
                                },
                                "vehicleLease": "MY RULE MY WORLD"
                            }
                        ],
                        "stops": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
 }
```

This is the expression I have tried:

```
$..vehicleCode[?($..vehicleLease=="AS PER LAW OF ENFORCMENT")
```

Comment: Please add comma after  "@type": "Segment" .

Comment: Where is your current query? What did you try? Do you hope somebody will do your home work?

Comment: @AshutoshDalai: You can edit your own question and add it by yourself. I would also recommend adding a better description of your issue.

Comment: @AKSW, Below is my expression

$..vehicleCode[?($..vehicleLease=="AS PER LAW OF ENFORCMENT")]

Comment: Clarify the question, incorporate the comment

Answer (score 0):

JSON library *Josson* is able to solve this question with its query language expression.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"StateOffers\" : [ [ {" +
    "    \"vehicleCode\" : 242214214," +
    "    \"vehiclePart\" : [ {" +
    "      \"@type\" : \"vehiclePart\"," +
    "      \"segments\" : [ {" +
    "        \"@type\" : \"Segment\"," +
    "        \"segmentOfferInformation\" : {" +
    "          \"vehicleMiles\" : 771," +
    "          \"awardFare\" : false" +
    "        }," +
    "        \"vehicleLease\" : \"AS PER LAW OF ENFORCMENT\"" +
    "      } ]," +
    "      \"stops\" : 0" +
    "    } ]" +
    "  }, {" +
    "    \"vehicleCode\" : 242214215," +
    "    \"vehiclePart\" : [ {" +
    "      \"@type\" : \"vehiclePart\"," +
    "      \"segments\" : [ {" +
    "        \"@type\" : \"Segment\"," +
    "        \"segmentOfferInformation\" : {" +
    "          \"vehicleMiles\" : 771," +
    "          \"awardFare\" : false" +
    "        }," +
    "        \"vehicleLease\" : \"MY RULE MY WORLD\"" +
    "      } ]," +
    "      \"stops\" : 0" +
    "    } ]" +
    "  } ] ]" +
    "}");
```

**Query**

```
Integer vehicleCode= josson.getInteger(
        "StateOffers.flatten()" +
        ".[vehiclePart.segments[vehicleLease = 'AS PER LAW OF ENFORCMENT']]" +
        ".vehicleCode");
System.out.println(vehicleCode);
//Output: 242214214
```